# Rails: Possible to have tableless entities that implement has_many and belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to create a set of "ActiveRecord" style classes that support `has_many` and `belongs_to` mixins but I dont need them to be tied to the database. The purpose of this is to aggregate data with a more strongly typed object then just using a collection of nested hashes.

Let me know if this doesn't make sense an I can edit my question with some sample code. Essentially the end goal is use the `.build` and `operator<<` methods to build some associated data.

Answer (score 0):

You can with tableless models

Install this gem and follow their documentation https://github.com/softace/activerecord-tableless

or, for a manual implementation, you can follow that asciicast http://asciicasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model